# How to disable hover on bootstrap 4 dropdown

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I have a page with a data grid, and in that grid every row has a bootstrap dropdown button/menu in it with actions you can perform against that data row. The problem is, the menu opens on hover, and I want it to be on click only (so the user doesn't accidentally open the menu on the wrong row).

Is there a way via CSS to tell the menus to not do anything on hover? I'd prefer not to use jquery for it, and as I have other dropdowns on the page outside the grid, I'd also like to target the ones in the grid specifically so I don't bung up the others.

Sample cell in ng-repeat row:

```
<td class="text-center" ng-if="vm.isCustService">
    <div class="dropdown drop-down-in-grid">
        <button type="button" id="btnCustDetails_{{$index}}"
                class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-ellipsis-v fa-lg"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="btnCustDetails">
            <div>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-nowrap" href="/CustomerDetails#/details/" id="lnkDetails_{{$index}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Customer Details</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-nowrap" href="/CustomerDetails#/addresses/" id="lnkAddresses_{{$index}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-address-book-o"></i> Addresses</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-nowrap" href="/CustomerDetails#/jobs/" id="lnkJobs_{{$index}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-o"></i> Jobs</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-nowrap" href="/CustomerDetails#/createJob/" id="lnkAddJob_{{$index}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-plus-o"></i> New Job</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-nowrap" href="/CustomerDetails#/notes/" id="lnkNotes_{{$index}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-word-o"></i> Notes</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-nowrap" href="/CustomerDetails#/statements/" id="lnkStatements_{{$index}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-money"></i> Statements</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-nowrap" href="/CustomerDetails#/orderSummary/" id="lnkOrderSummary_{{$index}}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-tasks"></i> Order Summary</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Wait, bootstrap 4 dropdowns don't toggle on hover [by design](https://markdotto.com/2012/02/27/bootstrap-explained-dropdowns/) so is there something else intentionally causing it? Would maybe need to see a working example.

Comment: I thought as much, and yet all of my bootstrap dropdowns toggle on hover. I've been searching through every instance of "hover" in every css or js file in my codebase, and I can't see anywhere that tells the dropdowns to have any hover action at all.

Comment: I opened DevTools (edge and chrome), clicked on the root div (with class="dropdown"), and opened the "Force Element State" panel... clicking the 'hover' checkbox makes the menu open up. But every class I see in the Styles panel is from within Bootstrap's scss files - stuff I don't ever edit, since I don't want to lose changes on upgrades. I'm honestly at a loss.

Comment: As a nuclear approach, I opened every file that had both "dropdown" and "hover", and commented out every line that had either of them, EXCEPT for the bootstrap files themselves.

And it still persists.

Comment: Can you recreate a snippit here on SO that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Not without building my entire website here. It's a large site, with a massive amount of .js and .css files, not to mention being MVC and AngularJS. And then there are all of the custom directives and modules... I was honestly hoping for a way to just force a decoupling of the hover event from the dropdown root div after it rendered.

Comment: If you see in the dev tools style summary which class is the culprit just override it if you need to quick 'n easy. So like if you see something like `.dropdown-in-grid button:hover .menu { display: block; }` you just add a class like `.dropdown-in-grid button:hover .menu { display: none !important; }` to move on with your day.

Comment: I was looking for something like that, and never could find it. Somehow, somewhere, we tied hover to "dropdown", and I'll be damned if I can see it. That said, I found a work-around. Turns out BS4 has several methods to creating drop downs, and using one that doesn't use the dropdown class turns out to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this style from your css

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```